# How do I share long lived resources between multiple controllers in Web API?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI controller class (inheriting from ApiController).

It needs to read data which which exists on disk.  I don't want to load from disk for every request.

So I'd like to find some way to inject the dependency into the controller.

Should I create a custom dependency resolver implementing IDependencyResolver?

What thread safety measures do I need to take for my dependency class?

Comment: A static property in a base controller will be fine. If you are only reading.. there are no threading issues to worry about.

Comment: Injecting a dependency alone will not solve your problem if the dependency is instantiated upon each request.

Comment: Simon, what do you mean a 'base controller'?  A new class with public static properties containing the dependencies, from which my controller can inherit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) to inject the dependency to any controllers you need.

To use the dependency injection for web api you need an other nuget package for ninject called "WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject".

Ninject creates a file calle "NinjectWebCommon.cs" in you App_Start folder where you can configure your dependencies.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ILogLivedResource>().To<LongLiveResourceInstance>().InRequestScope();;
}
```

More information you can find [here](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/).

Regards,
Mishu